# How do I map a Set of Objects in typescript

Tags: typescript, iterable

First time trying typescript.

I have an object that looks like

```
interface Job {
//... some data
    priority: number
}
```

and I want to return the highest priority from a Set of Jobs (note: not the Job itself, but the actual value). So naturally I just tried:

```
// let jobs: Set<Job> = fetchJobs();
jobs.map((job) => job.priority).max()
// or
jobs.values().map((job) => job.priority).max()
```

But it tells me`Uncaught TypeError: jobs.map is not a function`

Comment: `Set` indeed does not have a `map()` method, and arrays have no `max()` method.  You have to do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbAM8N) instead: `Math.max(...Array.from(jobs).map((job) => job.priority))`

Comment: Thats it! in the end I used `.reduce((acc, curr)=> acc>curr?acc:curr, 0)` but that's just because I need the default value to be 0

Comment: All right, wrote up an answer for completeness (but not touching the default of `0` because the whole `max` thing is out of scope for the question as asked).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Set` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) do not have a `map()` method, so it's not surprising that you're getting errors.  You might be thinking of [the `map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on [`Array` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead.  A `Set` is not an `Array`, although both are [*iterable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol).  Luckily you can convert any iterable into an `Array` in several ways:

You can pass it to [the static `Array.from()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
const jobArray = Array.from(jobs); // Job[]
```

Or you can [spread it into an array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax):

```
const jobArray = [...jobs]; // Job[]
```

Note that [the `values()` method of a `Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/values) produces the very same iterator that is used when you treat the `Set` as an iterator, so while you could use it, it's unnecessary:

```
const jobArray = Array.from(jobs.values()); // same thing

const jobArray = [...jobs.values()]; // also same thing
```

Once you have transformed the `Set` into an `Array` you can use `map()` and then process the result as needed:

```
const max = Math.max(...jobArray.map(j => j.priority)); // number
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgFIHsBGyDeBYAKGWOQHpSA6K5AZ3QFsUATOMOQk5ABymHV7ABPAFzIQAV3qZohAL6FCCdCBphkAKyw1RAZQhgAPBkwA+ZAF4xEAO7I9YABQBtHN179gQ0QFlWACwooOBAmBgcASmRZABpcNz4BEWRfMACgkLDI2QBdcIBuBQIQOEYaLkQUAEEoIMEAMSgGXELOJRU1TUxq2otkbrhBChhG+gdOmnyyUjQsJ2yOEjbVZDgAGzpjfsFeraGRsa0KADc18QgaCPyF4iW1ejgAD16UgPuHhyoKTt37rjGLMzqCg8BKeQThSbkMSSaRQQryAiEYqlcpIOw8CBwJjNRFERbKZbfGoDXpOT7jbJ5KYzTBza7IW4rdboTbE7aWMlUcbHU7nCKU+mMt7PfwUN4fLlYH5wP7qAEaYHuRIQqlQiRSGS4hGFJboVYQCirdAAcwcLzFjwlFF2wzC43CFr+B0wkXMgKwitBQghV1xuv1hpNZtF4s+Nv23JOqzOFwhjocztd7swno83pVQA)